# API Returns OK in API but no Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return an object in a model through another API I've made but when I fetch my API with GET on PostMan it only returns 200 OK but an empty array.

This is what I'm trying to get:

```json
[
  {
    "productId": 0,
    "quantity": 0
  }
]
```

And this is what I'm getting in PostMan

```json
[]
```

by calling with this API URL:

```
http://localhost:5700/api/Orders/basket/firstId
```

Here is my controller and the respective GET method on which I'm calling upon in Postman:

```cs
[HttpGet("basket/{identifier}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto>> FetchBasketEntries(string identifier)
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
       HttpMethod.Get,
       $"https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{identifier}")
    {
        Headers = { { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" }, }
    };

    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    using var httpResponseMessage =
        await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

    var basketEntires = Enumerable.Empty<BasketEntryDto>();

    if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return basketEntires;

    using var contentStream =
        await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

    var basketDTO = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
            <BasketDto>(contentStream, options);

    //basketDTO = new NewBasketDTO.ItemDTO
    //{
    //    ProductId = basketDTO.ProductId,
    //    Quantity = basketDTO.Quantity
    //};

    basketEntires = basketDTO.Entries.Select(x =>
        new BasketEntryDto
        {
            ProductId = x.ProductId,
            Quantity = x.Quantity
        }
    );

    return basketEntires; // 200 OK
}
```

Here is my `BasketDTO`:

```cs
public class BasketDto
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto> Entries { get; set; } = new List<BasketEntryDto>();
}
```

and my `BasketEntryDto`:

```cs
public class BasketEntryDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the original API in JSON:

```json
{
    "identifier": "mrPostMan",
    "items": [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

in which I want to get the `items` array and its object.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why is it returning an empty array? Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the states using the debugger?

Comment: In basketdto, have you tried naming the second property as items instead of entries?

Comment: @Stefan Yes a little bit but it just said 'null' on value I think, I'm trying now again to be sure

Comment: @kks21199 I'm going to try that now and see how it works out, thanks guys for helping out

Comment: @Stefan It says 'basketEntries: null'

Comment: @kks21199 Yes now it worked when I changed it to items! Thank you! But why didn't it work otherwise?

Comment: @NMNamuAgain Why would it ever think to take `items` from json and put it into `Entries` in C#? Would you also appreciate it if it decided to take user input and store it in a random variable of yours, not telling you in which?

Comment: @GSerg funny way to put it but that explained it, very much appreciated for the answer mate :D

Comment: @NMNamuAgain Glad it worked. I have added it as an answer along with another attribute that you could use if you still want to keep using `Entries` property in `BasketDTO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to change the `Entries` property in `BasketDTO` to `Items` to match with the JSON property name.

```
public class BasketDto
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto> Items { get; set; } = new List<BasketEntryDto>();
}
```

Alternatively, you could also explicitly mention the JSON Property name by using [JsonPropertyNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

```
public class BasketDto
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("items")] 
    public IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto> Entries { get; set; } = new List<BasketEntryDto>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, this worked, I see my mistake now, I don't have lots of knowledge regarding .NET :) but this was appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well this will work when there are more than 0 items (basket is not empty) but not when the basket is empty as:

```
basketEntires = basketDTO.Entries.Select(x =>
        new BasketEntryDto
        {
            ProductId = x.ProductId,
            Quantity = x.Quantity
        }
    );
```

there are no items, select will not work. so you can do like this:

```
if(basketEntires.Count == 0)
{
     basketEntires = new BasketEntryDto 
         { 
              ProductId = 0,
              Quantity  = 0 
         }
}

return basketEntires; // 200 OK
```

And don't forget to add `.ToList()`:

```
basketEntires = basketDTO.Entries.Select(x =>
    new BasketEntryDto
    {
        ProductId = x.ProductId,
        Quantity = x.Quantity
    }
).ToList();
```

You should not return `IEnumerable`, instead you should return list (or array).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Very much appreciated for helping out! Although I just changed the name of the IEnumerable in BasketDTO from Entries to Items after @kks21199 had adviced me to do so and that worked :D Anyways thanks guys for the help

Comment: @NMNamuAgain You are very welcome